# C# GUI Guessing Game

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I am trying to create a form guessing game in C#, that allows the user 100 guesses and counts how many times they are wrong and how many times they are right.  I used a for loop to try and accomplish this, however every time I enter a guess one counter will equal 1 and the other counter will equal 99.  The problem is that it doesn't exit the for loop and I can't figure out how to get it to exit.

```
namespace Assignment10
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] rando = new int[100];
    int answer;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int hoverNumber;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        start();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void nextGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        guessButton.Enabled = true;
        hoverBox.Text = "??";
    }
    public void start()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < rando.Length; x++)
        {
            rando[x] = random.Next(0, 100);
            hoverNumber = rando[x];
        }
    }

    private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        answer = Convert.ToInt32(GuessBox.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < rando.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (answer != rando[i])
                counter1++;
            else
                counter2++;
            for (int x = 0; x < 1; ++x)
            {
                if (answer != rando[i])
                {
                    nextGuess.Enabled = true;
                    guessButton.Enabled = false;
                    label3.Text = "The number incorrect is: " + counter1;
                    GuessBox.Clear();
                }
                else if (answer == rando[i])
                {
                    nextGuess.Enabled = true;
                    guessButton.Enabled = false;
                    label2.Text = "The number correct is: " + counter2;
                    GuessBox.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void mouseLabel_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hoverBox.Text = Convert.ToString(hoverNumber - 3);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Not even after 100 iterations? Thats how long your loop lasts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, the problem is probably in your `guessButton_Click` method, which is *very* messy. I'm assuming you only want to compare the guess to the current number, instead of going through the array. 1 guess per number, right? Anyways, since you already have counters for the number of correct and incorrect guesses, this simplifies things. Just check the guess against the array index of `counter1 + counter2`, like so:

```
private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    answer = Convert.ToInt32(GuessBox.Text);
    if (answer == rando[counter1+counter2])
    {
        counter2++;
        label2.Text = "The number of correct guesses is: " + counter2;
    }
    else (answer != rando[i])
    {
        counter1++;
        label3.Text = "The number if incorrect guesses is: " + counter1;
    }
    nextGuess.Enabled = true;
    guessButton.Enabled = false;
    GuessBox.Clear();
}
```